# Forward query parameters to ErrorDocument in an .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an ErrorDocument that handles 401 errors. It contains some logic to detect Kerberos errors and forward to a manual login page.

I would like to be able to forward all the query parameters to this document (in this particular example, the `redirect` parameter that I need to forward to the manual login page)

My `.htaccess` file

```
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

What happens with my actual configuration

1. Request to `/path/something?redirect=/foo/bar` returns a 401
2. The user is redirected to `/errors/401.php`

The example of what I'd like to achieve

1. Request to `/path/something?redirect=/foo/bar` returns a 401
2. The user is redirected to `/errors/401.php?redirect=/foo/bar`

Comment: You already have `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']` that will contain `redirect=/foo/bar`